# Validating numeric uniqueness of two attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, unique

I have a model `Track` which has two attributes:

`disc` which represents what disc the track belongs to and `number` which represents the numeric order of the track on the album.

I'd like to validate the uniqueness of the track number to where there can only be one unique track number per disc. So for instance on Disc 1 (or Disc 2) there can only be one track with a track `number` of 1.

Is there a pre-existing way to do this in Rails' uniqueness validation where one attribute is dependent on another? If not what would be the best way to write the custom validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `validates_uniqueness_of` with `scope`:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :number, scope: [:disc, album_id]
```

By the way, on the database level you should also validate it with `unique index`:

```
add_index :table_name , [:number, :disc, :album_id], unique: true
```

or use a gem providing a composite primary key feature.

Comment: Thanks. Up until now I never realized that `scope` could be used to target attributes. Out of curiosity, do you have a gem off-hand that you'd recommend that would accomplish this? Granted, adding the index to the db is easy enough but always open in hearing alternatives.

Comment: @Carl Edward:There is [this implementation](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys), but you should also look through discussions about using it (you can find some on this site, actually).

Comment: Hey, so it looks like the current validation ensures that only one track in the entire db has a number of one instead of validating just the album it belongs to. I'm wondering what would be the best way to to direct it to the `album_id` it has on record.

Comment: @CarlEdwards : Can you elaborate one more time? It this the same issue or a new one?)

Comment: No same issue. Let's say I have an album that has a track `number` of 1 and `disc` number of 1. It will ensure that there are no duplicates. But if I were to create another album with a `disc` number of 1 and `track` number of 1 I get a validation error. Basically the validation scope shouldn't exceed the scope of that particular album. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CarlEdwards : What is your rails version btw?

Comment: Rails 4. That seemed to do that trick. Never thought I'd learn so much in just one post on rails validations. When you get a chance could you update your answer to reflect the adjustment?